# cannot delete a stream because Package Metadata in Repository say not all releases DELETED

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I'm a Spring Data Cloud Flow newbie and I'm having a hard time getting rid of a stream.

```
stream list
```

shows I have a stream named `ticktock5`.

```
stream undeploy ticktock5
stream destroy ticktock5
```

result in the same error:

```
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: Can not delete Package Metadata [ticktock5:1.0.0] in Repository [local]. Not all releases of this package have the status DELETED. Active Releases [ticktock5]
```

This is running on

```
macOS 10.12.6, 
java 1.8.0_161, 
Docker 2.0.0.0-mac81(29211),  
Spring Cloud Data Flow 1.7.2.RELEASE
```

Reproduction is simple:

```
Create a stream
Deploy it
Wait
After a period of time (5 min or longer), the deployment will fail.
No errors are given in the data flow server log
```

Comment: It'd be useful if you can share more details about your environment and the versions in use. If it is reproducible, please do also share the steps in entirety.

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: Thank you! Can you also share the logs for when the deployment failed? Is that consistent?

Comment: Also, what version of Skipper are you using. Both the SCDF and Skipper-server logs would be useful to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up recreating my Docker/K8s environment and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed by altering tables in **skipper** database. (In my case mysql db)

Steps performed.

- Delete the stream from skipper_release

`delete from skipper_release where name = 'my-stuck-stream-name'`

- Delete the stream from skipper_app_deployer_data

`delete from skipper_app_deployer_data where release_name = 'my-stuck-stream-name'`

- Delete the stream from skipper_package_metadata

`delete from skipper_package_metadata where name = 'my-stuck-stream-name'`

- If you are facing problem with un-deploy the stream then manually delete the resources. (I am using kubernetes platform, so I have deleted deployments and services related to that stream)

Comment: Deleting the rows from those tables worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as answered above this worked for me:

```
delete from skipper_release where name = 'streamName'
delete from skipper_app_deployer_data where release_name = 'streamName'
delete from skipper_package_metadata where name = 'streamName'
```

PS: i don't have enough reputation points to upvote that :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).